# I changed my godaddy domain's nameservers, but it continues to direct to the old host

Tags: domain, hosting

I've completed creating a website for a client and the time has come for the go-live. They originally had a wix website (wix is a DIY website builder) and had their godaddy domains point to it.

Since wix is hosting the current site, and I've made them a new site, we are ditching wix for a new hosting service (HostGator). I uploaded a simple index.html to the hostgator server (in public_html) and changed the nameservers for their domain. It's been about an hour and the domains still direct me to the wix site.

Does this take time? If so, how long, and how can I speed it up? The website needs to go live tonight. Let me know what information is needed to help address the problem. Thanks in advance.

update: **I've checked my DNS Zone File via my godaddy portal and I am seeing a TTL of 1 hour for everything, but nothing under "NS" (see pic). It's been about several hours at this point.** Does this mean I've done something wrong in the process?

picture of my dns zone file via godaddy portal:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkPUc.jpg

Comment: Have you done any research into how DNS works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the changes were all correctly made, not much you can do except wait it out.  See:

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/dns-name-servers/propagation-times

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1746/what-factors-affect-dns-propagation-time

Comment: I am pinging the domains but the ip given is not matching the IP address that I am given in my host gator cPanel. Is this an okay way of checking that the domain has transferred?